# Android Is there way to know when i am releasing my finger from a gallery widget?

Tags: android

I want to call a function the moment i realease my finger from a Gallery.Is there a way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting an OnTouchListener for your gallery and fire the method from there

```
gallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
{           
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
   {
    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        //Finger has been released from gallery         
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
  }
});
```